# Unable to create/drop a foreign key on a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have searched for the answer to this and only come up with the basic answers on creating/dropping a foreign key etc.
I have a large table and created a foreign key, however during creation the server crashed so the key was not created.
But, if I try to create the key I get a SQL 1005 error "duplicate key on write or update", and if I try to drop the key I get a SQL 1025 error "cannot delete a parent row" which after querying the Innodb engine status translates to "cannot find a constraint with the given id". I cannot find the key by querying the information_schema, so how does MySQL know of its existence when I try to create it and yet cannot find it when I try to drop it, it must be logged somewhere. I am sort of stuck and hoping that I do not have to delete and recreate the table. Any ideas on resolving this welcome.

Comment: learn how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for the multiple tables involved here (there are more than one), follow **Section2** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) . Note that for you it is not about SQLFiddle.Help us to help you.